# Returning promises for model properties in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise

I am working on a [habit tracking app](https://github.com/wholcomb/habit_tracker). It is written in Ember and backed by CouchDB.

On the main screen I want to show a list of habits and the last time an event was recorded for each. Here are what my models look like:

```
App.Habit = DS.Model.extend( {
  type: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: 'habit' } ),
  name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  color: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  events: DS.hasMany( 'event', { async: true, defaultValue: [] } ),
  style: function() {
    return 'background-color: %@'.fmt( this.get( 'color' ) )
  }.property( 'color' ),
  lastTime: function() {
    return this
      .get( 'events' )
      .then( function( events ) {
        var times = events.map( function( e ) {
          return e.get( 'time' )
        } )
        return times.length == 0 ? undefined : times.sort()[0]
      } )
  }.property( 'events' ),
} )

App.Event = DS.Model.extend( {
  type: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: 'event' } ),
  time: DS.attr( 'date' ),
  habit: DS.belongsTo( 'habit' )
} )
```

Note that the `lastTime` property of `Habit`, returns a promise. When I did it without the promise the array was length 0. My handlebars template looks like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="habits">
  <div id="habits">                                                                                                                                                                                        
    {{#each}}                                                                                                                                                                                              
      <div class="row" {{action 'createEvent' id}}>
        <div class="col-xs-1 color" {{bind-attr style=style}}></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">{{name}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" data-role="timer">{{format-time-numeric lastTime}}</div>
      </div>                                                                                                                                                                                               
    {{/each}}                                                                                                                                                                                              
  </div>
</script>
```

The `format-time-numeric` helper is just:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper( 'format-time-numeric', function( time ) {
  return moment( time ).format( 'YYYY/M/D @ H:mm' )
} )
```

The `time` getting passed to moment is a promise and is rendering as a bunch of `NaN`s. If I pass a promise back from `format-time`, it renders as `[object]`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding your problem. What exactly is the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a dependent property, `lastTime`, that is computed from an array, `events`. I am using CouchDB and `this.get('events')` returns a promise. I need to search that returned array and display the value in the template. If I search via the `then` method of the promise and return the resultant promise, that promise, rather than the derived value, is passed to the display template. If I call `this.get('events').map` the result is 0 length. I thought Ember was supposed to wait for the promises to complete and send the results to the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your could use `reduceComputed` property for this case:

```
  maxTime: Ember.reduceComputed('events.@each.time', {
    initialValue: -Infinity,
    addedItem: function(accValue, event) { 
      return Math.max(accValue, event.get('time'));
    },
    removedItem: function(accValue, event) { 
      if (event.get('time') < accValue ) {
        return accValue;
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Ember Data expert but try using async:false in events.
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107/4

Also you can put in a debugger: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_debugger

Comment: When I change `async` to `false`, I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined`. The internet suggests this might be because my data model is corrupt, but it seems to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return a promise from the

```
lastTime
```

Instead, write it as:

```
lastTime: function() {
    var times =  this.get('events').map(function(event) {
                      return event.get('time');
                  });      
    return times.length == 0 ? undefined : times.sort()[0]
  } )
}.observes('events').property(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model's logic is flawed.  It is observing changes in 'events' but then also getting 'events' via a Promise.  If 'events' has already been resolved then you do not require the Promise.  If 'events' has not then you cannot observe it.

Models are generally not the place for Promises - your view does not understand how to display a Promise.  Promises are generally resolved in Routes and the results stored in Models.  I would rearchitect to move it to the Route or if this is not possible have some action or observer set the property in the model.

Option 1: If events are already in memory:

See Hrishi answer

Option 2: If events are not in memory and a Promise is required:

Something like this may work:

```
lastTime: null,
```

And then in your controller have an action similar to this (or use some other way of trigger similar code):

```
lastTimeAction: function() {
   var self = this;
   this.get( 'events' ).then( function( events ) {
      var times = events.map( function( e ) {
         return e.get( 'time' );
      });
      self.set('lastTime', times.length == 0 ? undefined : times.sort()[0]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from your comment:

> I thought Ember was supposed to wait for the promises to complete and send the results to the template.

That is... a tricky question. To put it simply, no, it won't wait. The only time that I can think of that id *does* wait is in the model hooks. If you return a promise from `beforeModel`, `model`, or `afterModel`, the router will pause before continuing. However, that doesn't apply to controllers or templates, and doesn't apply to your situation when you're getting the async relationship of a model.

So, one potential solution for you is to pause the router until the `events` relationship is loaded. Something like this in your router:

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('habit', params.habit_id).then(function(habit) {
        // Return another promise, to continue pausing the router
        return habit.get('lastTime');
    });
}
```

That will pause the router (and not render your template) until your `lastTime` property fully computes.

Another option (which I recommend) is to just have the `lastTime` property inserted into the template asynchronously. If you change the way the property is computed, you can have the template update when the `events` are fetched:

```
lastTime: function() {
    var events = this.get('events');

    if (events.length <= 0) {
        return 0; // Or some other default
    }

    return events.mapBy('time').sort()[0];
}.property('events.@each.time')
```

So your template will initially show 0, but then update with the real time when `events` is ready.

The third option, as Michael Benin mentioned, is to set the `events` relationship on your model to be a synchronous one. You could compute your property immediately, but you'd have to include all of the `events` models in your JSON whenever you fetched a `habit` model. (Not recommended. Embrace the asynchronous.)